# Set default file permission separately from directory permission with ACL on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, access-control-list

This works perfectly for setting default permissions:

```
setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx -m o::rx /var/www/html
```

Unfortunately, it sets default permissions on both dir's and files.

How do I set dir and file permissions separately?

You'd think the -M (modify file) switch would work, but only gives `No such file or directory`.

Have read elsewhere that using a capital X should set permissions only on dir's, e.g., `g::rwX`, but doesn't work.

Comment: +1 simply because `setfacl` question. I always forget to use file ACLs, but for some reason it always gives me a warm, fuzzy feeling when I'm reminded they exist.